# watir-webdriver Wait method for IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to get my code(developed with Watir for IE8) working with watir-webdriver and IE9.
Currently I have an issue with waiting.

For example

```
Watir::Wait.until{browser.button(:value, "Login").exists?}
```

It doesn't wait and gives me next error

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.12.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:50:in `assert_ok': Unable to find element with xpath == .//button[
text()='Login'] | .//input[@value='Login' and (@type='button' or @type='reset' or @type='submit' or @type='image')] (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnexpectedJavascriptError
)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.12.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.12.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:58:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.12.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:58:in `create_response'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.12.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:64:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.12.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:39:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.12.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:450:in `raw_execute'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.12.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:428:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.12.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:396:in `find_element_by'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.12.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/search_context.rb:41:in `find_element'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.3.9/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/element_locator.rb:86:in `find_first_by_multiple'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.3.9/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/element_locator.rb:33:in `locate'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.3.9/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/button.rb:53:in `locate'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.3.9/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:259:in `assert_exists'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.3.9/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:36:in `exists?'
        from 1.rb:20:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.12.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/wait.rb:36:in `until'
        from 1.rb:20:in `<main>'
```

Tried same script with IE8, and have the same issue.
Of course I can workaround it with sleep, but it's not very good idea.
If I do sleep for few seconds before wait, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
browser.button(:value, "Login").wait_until_present
```

More info: http://rubydoc.info/github/jarib/watir-webdriver/master/Watir/Element#wait_until_present-instance_method

Comment: This didn't helped but I found the problem. My use case is next.I goto https server via IE9 and got certificate error page. To handle this page I'm using wscript commands and just clicking tab to get to override link. Wait method goes right after {enter} on override link command and in this case it craches. If i go to this https server again after overridelink clicked Wait command is working as expected. BTW this code worked for FF and chrome without extra go command.

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening immediately after a certification error page due to your test server using an 'invalid' (self signed) cert then you have two options.

1) Add the cert(s) from your test server(s) to your the pool of trusted root cert authorities on your client test system(s).  This makes IE treat those certs as if they came from a trusted provider. (never do this for a site on the net, only for test servers you or someone in your company controls)

2) hardwire a sleep in there.

The problem is happening because IE9 does some special stuff on that cert page that blocks 
javascript and prevents webdriver from accessing pretty much anything on the page.  Even simple basic methods like 'browser.text' will fail on that page, much less checking for an element existing.  The first check for the login button is happening while the invalid cert warning page is still displayed, and that's what causes the error.  If the page is never displayed, or you wait just a tiny bit of time, then you won't see that error.

What MS is doing on that page is designed to prevent a malware site from automating a response that would take you forward into their site.  Good stuff security wise, but it is also blocking Webdriver from accessing the page.  I doubt the webdriver folks will find a way past this, and if they do I'd expect MS to close down what they would view as a 'security hole' shortly afterwards.

For testing I'm convinced that the best practice is just to add self-signed certs from testbed servers to your trusted root providers list on your test client systems. That eliminates the warnings and furthermore is faster and easier than dealing with it in all of your automation. It also duplicates the user experience when they hit your genuine production server which no doubt has a valid certificate and never produces that warning.

I used to be dedicated to finding ways of 'scripting around' that stuff, but realized I was just being stubborn and should take the easier more practical path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but adding certificate manually doesn't work for me, because, I need to do it every time new server build arrives(2-3 times per week) and scripts are executed on 20+ machines.

Comment: Well then you just need to hard-code a sleep in there that is long enough to ensure that webdriver is never trying to access that bad cert page.   Or your find a way to get the certs registered as valid on those test systems.  (maybe wscript to do that?) Are they rebuilding the certificates each time?  The other option might be to setup a local system that can act as an 'authority' and issue certs for those servers that can be kept in place for a long duration.  Then add that 'authority' to your test systems base images so that it will always show up as being valid.